# Settings Window design - binding Page to TreeViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm just starting with WPF (coming from WinForms) and I want to make settings window like the one in Visual Studio. Category tree on left side and appropriate views on the right.

In WinForms I did it by adding to TreeViewItem's TAG name of the window that should be displayed and then in OnClick I was creating that window using reflection. Something like this:

```
//pseudocode
TreeViewItem item = CreateTreeViewItem(); 
item.Tag = "GeneralSettingsWindow";
item.Text = "General settings";
------------------------------------------------------------------------
void ItemClick(object sender)
{
    TreeViewItem item = sender as TreeViewItem;
    string formName = item.Tag.ToString();
    BaseSettingsForm f = Activator.CreateInstance(formName);
    settingsPanel.Controls.Clear();
    settingsPanel.Controls.Add(f);
}
```

And it worked fine.
I'm curious how can I achieve that functionality using WPF binding. Is it possible anyway?

Answer (score 1):

I have done a tree view in left side and when you click an item it will update the contents of right side panel. In order to do that you have to make two panels or grid in an window, one in left side with less width and another in right side. Then put the tree view in the left side and update the contents of right side grid by adding different types of user controls or by showing and hiding different grids with the corresponding click of tree view item.

Here is an example of making the tree view and you can modify that according to your own requirement.

```html
<TreeView MouseLeftButtonUp="Get_MFR" SelectedItemChanged="treeviewQuestion_SelectedItemChanged" 
x:Name="treeviewQuestion" FontFamily="Nunito" FontSize="16" Padding="10 10" 
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
BorderThickness="0" Margin="0,0,0,27"
>

<TreeView.Resources>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
<Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
<Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
<Setter.Value>
<DataTemplate>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10 2">
<TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}},Path=Tag,
Converter={x:Static local:TagToTextConverter.Instance}}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
<Rectangle Margin="5" Width="10" Height="10" Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}},Path=Tag,
Converter={x:Static local:TagToColorConverter.Instance}}"/>
</StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
</TreeView.Resources>

</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though you're new to WPF development, I'd still suggest you take a look at the MVVM design pattern. The separation between user interface and business logic makes this type of application structure much more straightforward.

Replace your settings panel with a `ContentControl`, and define as many `DataTemplates` as you require for different tree node types. You can then bind its `Content` property to the selected `TreeViewItem`.

Unfortunately, "out of the box" WPF doesn't support binding to the selected item in a `TreeView`. However, there are several ways around that, including using a `Behaviour`, which I described in a recent [blog post](http://peregrinesview.uk/wpf-behaviors-part-2-treeview/).

Comment: I don't know which approach is preferred in WPF, but I'd rather have those views in separate files. There will be also some logic in UI (not business logic) according to different settings.